# RubyOnRails - Creating new objects with relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

i have 2 models, User and Technician

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :technician
end


class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user, presence: true
end
```

When creating a new Technician and trying to associate with an existing User it gives the error: `User cannot be blank`

the view of Technician.new (form) is:

```
    <%= form_for(@technician) do |f| %>
  <% if @technician.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@technician.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this technician from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @technician.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :codigo %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :codigo %><br><br>

    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map{|u|[u.nome, u.id]}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong if, selecting an user from the `select` it won't associate it to the attribute `user_id`?

Thanks

Comment: can you paste the code where you are creating a new Technician and trying to associate with an existing User.

Comment: did you check what is the value that select box passing as param? and also once check this you have given "u.nome" i think it should be "u.name"

Comment: the code is the above (form) the u.nome is correct, it's the attribute name (in Portuguese). Isn't the select box passing as param the u.id?

Comment: You have given validation to user and the select box includes one blank element, so if you not select any user it gives you error please check in this way once.

Comment: I selected one one the form and it doesn't associates...

Comment: Can you please post the output from console when form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using with `collect` like this

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.all.collect {|u|[u.nome, u.id]}) %>
```

**OR**

If you are using Rails 4,you can use `pluck`

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.pluck(:nome, :id))
```

For more details see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)**

If that doesn't work,change your validation in `Technician` model like this

```
class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**Update**

As you are using **`Rails4`**,you should be adding **`user_id`** to the **`permitted parameters`** like this

```
def your_params

params.require(:technician).permit(:user_id,:codigo)

end
```

Comment: The 'collect' and the 'pluck' didn't work... I can't change the validation on the Technician model because I have to be sure that a technician is an existing user... Do I have to indicate to "someone" that the form is going to retrive another attribute? In this case, the user_id?

Comment: I've changed the validation as you asked and now it says that the user_id can't be blank... Do I have to change anything on the Technician controller to accept the user_id field from the form? Keep in mind that the user_id attribute on the Technician was added on an after migration, not when the Model was created...

Comment: @NunoRibeiro Do you used strong params? If so post it in the question.

Comment: @NunoRibeiro Which Rails version you used?

Comment: @NunoRibeiro Then you will be using strong params right.Post those in the question.

Comment: sorry but, where are they?

Comment: @NunoRibeiro Post your full controller code please.

Comment: Thanks to you I figure it out, just have to add the attribute to the  params_require, right?

Comment: If you whish to change your answer indicate the adding of the attributes on the params_require, I would gladly rate your answer

Comment: @NunoRibeiro I edited my answer.Please rate it and accept it :)